# Openbox in 17.10.1

Tags: 17.10, openbox

I am currently running Server with no gui, i'd like to use the most lightweight gui possible since this installation will only be used to control one application.

So far i've tried

```
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox obconf
```

but no gui launches at startup

If I run `exec openbox-session` it will reset back to the login screen, I think it might print an error for half a second but it's too fast for me to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use

```
startx
```

To start the xserver. I also created a `.xinitrc` file inside of my home and put inside `start openbox-session` openbox launches after that.
I don't know why startx doesn't launch on it's own... for now I've added it to my .profile but if there is a better way please let me know.