# Want to move from Arch to Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I have been using Arch Linux for some weeks now and I am thinking  moving to Ubuntu right now.

I was configuring openbox on Arch and when I ask the community some basic question I was very upset the way they respond to me.

All is because Arch community act very disrespectful on me and even warn me to block me if I ask such question again.

Is there any way (guide) I can set up Openbox on Ubuntu?

Comment: Just a thought but Lubuntu, an official Ubuntu flavor, has Openbox as its default window manager.

Comment: Is this link too sparse for you:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013669/openbox-in-17-10-1?

Answer (score 1):

A search using Google produces a number of relevant hits, including:

https://www.lifewire.com/install-openbox-using-ubuntu-4051832

The basic instructions are to install Openbox using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install openbox obconf
```

Then:

Click on the icon in the top right corner and then choose log out.

Click on the little icon to the right of your username and you will now see two options:

1. Openbox
2. Ubuntu Default

Click on "Openbox".

Log in to your user account as normal.